# Bing webmaster tool's SEO reports complain about multiple <h1> tags?

Tags: bing, tags, heading, bing-webmaster-tools

I have analyzed my websites in Bing Webmaster Tools and it's showing the error “There are multiple `<h1>` tags on the page.”

I have analyze the pages manually and I haven’t found multiple H1 tags on any of them.

Why is this error is being show in webmaster tools?

[image]

Comment: Is there an option in those tools "View source as Bing!", might give you some insights

Answer (score 1):

I only see one H1 tag in your pages as well.   I'm not sure why Bing is telling you that there are multiple.

Even if there were multiple H1 tags, its not a problem that I would take the time to fix.  There should be only one `<title>` tag in a page, but multiple `<h1>` tags [can make sense](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824) as headings to equal major sections within the page.

Google doesn't have a problem with multiple H1 tags in a page.   Google's [Matt Cutts says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM) that multiple H1 tags (in moderation) are just fine with Google's ranking algorithms.

If you get the majority of your traffic from Bing, then you might want to try to figure out how to make it happy.   Your site would be the rare site if Google doesn't contribute 10x the amount of traffic that Bing does.

Comment: Thanks for your Answers Stephen! I got your point. I hope this issue will be get resolved in next crawl of Bing bots.